# Error when I'm invoking an AWS lambda, using python. Error: positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I'm using a lambda to invoke another one with this piece of code:

```
import boto3
import json

# Lambda Handler
def lambla_handler(event,context):

    lam = boto3.client('lambda', region_name='sa-east-1')

    try:
        response = lam.invoke(FunctionName='water_types', InvocationType='RequestResponse') 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
    print(response)
```

Everything is working fine, however when the lambda 'water_types' is getting this error:

```
water_types() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given: TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 250, in handle_event_request
result = request_handler(json_input, context)
TypeError: water_types() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

As I can see, I'm not sending any arguments. Any idea how to fix it?

```
def water_types(): 
   return print("water updated: 90")
```

Comment: Can you please show the handler of `water_types`? I thinks you're missing the mandatory `(event, context)` arguments

Comment: Yes, it is. Do I always need to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `water_types` is the handler of a function (which according to your code it is) you need to follow [AWS guidelines on how to create lambda functions with Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html)

A lambda handler needs to have an structure similar to

```py
def handler_name(event, context): 
    ...
    return some_value
```

The lambda runtime will provide values for `event` and `context` when it calls the handler.

So TL;DR, your function needs to look like this

```py
def water_types(event, context): 
   return print("water updated: 90")
```

You're not required to do anything with those parameters, but they need to be there.